# Visual C# Creating a text file on the desktop access denied

Tags: c#

my code when the form loads:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    // Create a file to write to. 
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("test");
    }

}
```

This is the error I constantly recieve: http://gyazo.com/bd623e67a24408ac3e71b5cc79a30f94

Comment: So you're trying to create a file with the same name as the Desktop folder? Not going to work...

Comment: I was trying to create a new textfile on the desktop, I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: @urbexppxuc Look at the question LokiSinclair linked. The solution is there, just look at the answer.

Answer (score 4):

What your code is doing right now is attempting to create a file with the same exact name as the Desktop folder. To create a new file, you'll need to append a file name to the end of your path string. Try something like this:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
if (!File.Exists(path + @"\test.txt"))
{
    // Create a file to write to.
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(path + @"\test.txt"))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

The `@` symbol in the strings makes the compiler ignore any escape characters in the string, treating them as a string literal. This code will check if a file named test.txt exists on your Desktop. If not, it creates one and writes "test" to it.

Comment: Just use Path.Combine instead